# Inconsistency between byte representations of IEEE754 single-precision floats

Tags: c, floating-point, common-lisp, ieee-754

This issue arose when using Common Lisp to read from a data file containing binary encodings of single-precision floats, presumably written from C/C++. In Lisp I used `decode-float32` from the [ieee-floats](https://github.com/marijnh/ieee-floats) package. However this resulted in floats with slightly different significands to those read by a C program reading the same floats.

On the face of it the code for `ieee-floats:decode-float32` appears to be faithful to the description of IEEE754 single floats from [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format). Furthermore this online [IEEE-754 Floating Point Converter](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) agrees with the behaviour.

So two questions. Why is the C version inconsistent? And how could you replicate the C behaviour in Lisp?

This was all carried out on x86_64 GNU/Linux with recent versions of sbcl, gcc and clang.

Below is some code I used to experiment with and confirm the behaviour.

Here is some C code to generate some random floats and their representations as bytes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int COUNT = 16;

void main () {
  float f;
  uint32_t i;
  char* pf = (char *)&f;
  char* pi = (char *)&i;

  for(int j=0; j<COUNT; j++) {
    f = (float)rand()/(float)(RAND_MAX/2.0) - 1.0;
    pf = (char *)&f;
    pi = (char *)&i;
    memcpy(pi, pf, sizeof(float));
    printf("%9f #x%x\n", f, i);
  }
}
```

And here is some Lisp code to read those floats and bytes and compare the Lisp encodings with the C encodings.

```
(ql:quickload '(:iterate :ieee-floats))

(defun scan (&optional (file "floats_and_bytes.dat"))
  (with-open-file (in file)
    (iter (for f next (read in nil))
          (for b next (read in nil))
          (while (and f b))
          (format t "~9f ~x ~x ~b~%"
                  f
                  (ieee-floats:encode-float32 f)
                  b
                  (- (ieee-floats:encode-float32 f) b)))))
```

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre]. The C `rand` function is not standardized to provide the same sequences on all C implementations. Identify a single example for which the behavior differs, provide a C program and a Lisp program that reproduces the behavior with that single example, and show the output from each program.

Comment: @user3414663, Try using `printf("%.9g #x%x\n", f, i);` and see if problem remains.

Comment: If there is any actual discrepancy, then it is not a matter of the C language itself or of Lisp itself.  It would be a matter of the programs involved or of the specific language *implementations* in use.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Your suggestion solves the problem. It's a print formatting issue. C (or more specifically as @john-bollinger pointed out the C *implementation* ) prints those randoms only to 7 decimal places with ```%f``` whether you use ```%9f``` or ```%99f```

Comment: _"whether you use `%9f` or `%99f`"_ -- These specify field widths, but do not specify a precision. The default precision for `%f` is 6 places after the decimal point. [This is mandated by the C Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p8), i.e., it is not an implementation detail. If your _implementation_ is printing 7 decimal places by default, then your implementation is not conforming to the Standard. To specify a precision you must use `.` followed by a precision, e.g., `%10.7f` or `%.7f`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Common [`float`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_standard:_binary32), with its 24-bit binary significand, needs up to **9 significant decimal digits** to uniquely print a `float` value (along with a sign and possible exponent).

`printf("%9f #x%x\n", f, i);` prints values in the (-1.0 ... + 1.0) range using 9 total characters:  `' '` or `'-'`, `'0'`, `'.'`, 6 digits.  This is, at best, 6 significant digits.

---

Suggested change (along with some minor C improvements):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int COUNT = 16;

int main() {
  union {
    float f;
    uint32_t i;
  } x;

  for (int j = 0; j < COUNT; j++) {
    x.f = (float) rand() / ((float) (RAND_MAX /2 + 1)) - 1.0f;
    printf("% .9g #x%lx\n", x.f, (unsigned long) x.i);
  }
}
```

Sample output

```
 0.380002022 #x3ec28fa0
 0.0108368397 #x3c318d00  // 10 digits after the '.', yet 9 significant digits.
 0.182981133 #x3e3b5f68
 0.109569788 #x3de06620
-0.243142366 #xbe78fa50
-0.484535754 #xbef81512
-0.585235715 #xbf15d202
 0.252523899 #x3e814ad0
-0.319745898 #xbea3b5bc
 0.687703729 #x3f300d5a
-0.862443924 #xbf5cc920
-0.180186212 #xbe3882bc
 0.75998807 #x3f428e94
-0.3610394 #xbeb8da28
 0.961136341 #x3f760d08
-0.829990387 #xbf547a40
```